# Prettier format on save formats file but leaves changes unsaved

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

On save, the file is formatted as it should be, but the formatted file is left unsaved, so that I need to ctrl+s twice to actually format and save a given file.

This is a very recent issue, not sure if it just started with the latest insiders build or a new version of Prettier. I've removed all other extensions, reinstalled prettier, etc, but nothing has helped so far.

Anyone else seen the same issue?

It's not an issue with the Ctrl-S keybinding, that's set to default for me, and I see no issues in the debugger:

```
[2021-07-16 20:55:09.729] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+S
[2021-07-16 20:55:09.729] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, matched workbench.action.files.save, when: no when condition, source: built-in.
```

Comment: If your not working on a VSCode extension, VSCode its-self, or doing work, like bug fixes for VSCode, or anything else VSCode related, but you are using VSCode to work on Non-VSCode  related projects, then you should be using the standard VSCode version — not insiders.

Comment: Have you tried troubleshooting the __[CTRL] + [S]__ keybinding, with the keyboard shortcut troubleshooting tool, and the output window? To be blunt, you shouldn't even be posting this question until you see the Keybinding log output for the __[CTRL] + [S]__ keybinding. (which should be part of your question, as its important information for solving this issue)

Comment: Whether or not I prefer to be on insiders is not relevant to the question, though it's likely a new bug introduced in insiders based on the fact that I don't see anyone screaming about it. Updated with keyboard info.

Comment: Wow, if its unlikely, then its not impossible, and its far more possible than you think. This sounds like a newer bug that prettier, or VSCode is unaware of, or a mistake on being made on the users end. Its a weird bug, I looked, no one else is complaining about it. You should at least, at the very least open up your standard version of VSCode (the blue one). I'd be willing to bet, that you can either get it to work in the standard VSCode edition, or in a completely default environment, with no settings set, except `"format.onSave": true`, and all extensions disabled except prettier.

Comment: That's the standard troubleshooting procedure for someone in your position. 9 out of 10 times you'll get it to work, doing what I just mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a new insiders issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128869